# PyQt5 - Assigning action to button class to update a label attribute from a different class

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm creating a calculator app using PyQt5, and when I'm assigning an action to my button to update the label text that resides in a different class from the button class. It seems to be doing something, but instead of what I'm expecting to happen. It seems to remove all of my calculator buttons, and rebuild the label without even updating its text. Please see attached screenshots for before and after I clicked a button.

```
import PyQt5.QtWidgets as qtwidget
import PyQt5.QtGui as qtgui
import PyQt5.QtCore as qtcore


app = qtwidget.QApplication([])

class Button(qtwidget.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super().__init__(text, parent=parent)
        self.text = text
        button_policy = self.sizePolicy()
        button_policy.setVerticalPolicy(button_policy.Policy.Minimum)
        self.setSizePolicy(button_policy)
        
        # Set text font style & size
        self.setFont(qtgui.QFont('Helvetica', 20))
        
        # assign click action to button_click function
        self.clicked.connect(self.button_click)
    
    # The problem seeems to be here
    def button_click(self):
        # declare MainWindow class
        label_obj = MainWindow()
        
        # access label attribute of MainWindow class
        label_text = label_obj.label
        
        # Set text of label to button text
        label_text.setText(self.text)
        
btn_percent = Button('%')
btn_ce = Button('CE')
btn_c = Button('C')
btn_back = Button('Back')
btn_sign = Button('+/-')
btn1 = Button('1')
btn2 = Button('2')
btn3 = Button('3')
btn4 = Button('4')
btn5 = Button('5')
btn6 = Button('6')
btn7 = Button('7')
btn8 = Button('8')
btn9 = Button('9')
btn0 = Button('0')
btn_division = Button('/')
btn_multiply = Button('x')
btn_minus = Button('-')
btn_plus = Button('+')
btn_dot = Button('.')
btn_equal = Button('=')

class MainWindow(qtwidget.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
            # Add a title
        self.setWindowIcon(qtgui.QIcon('.\icons\calculator_icon.ico'))
        self.setWindowTitle('Calculator')
        
        # Create a label
        self.label = qtwidget.QLabel("0")
        # Set background color
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: #e3e1da;\
                                border: 1px solid black;\
                                padding-top: 10px;\
                                padding-bottom: 10px")
        
        # Set label maximum height
        self.label.setMaximumHeight(100)
        
        # Align label text
        self.label.setAlignment(qtcore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignVCenter | qtcore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight)        
        
        # Set label text font and size
        self.label.setFont(qtgui.QFont('Helvetica', 40))
        
        # Add grid layout for calculator buttons
        main_gridlayout = qtwidget.QGridLayout()
        
        # Add label to main widget
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        
        # Add buttons to main widget
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn_percent, 1, 0)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn_ce, 1, 1)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn_back, 1, 2)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn_division, 1, 3)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn7, 2, 0)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn8, 2, 1)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn9, 2, 2)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn_multiply, 2, 3)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn4, 3, 0)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn5, 3, 1)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn6, 3, 2)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn_minus, 3, 3)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn1, 4, 0)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn2, 4, 1)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn3, 4, 2)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn_plus, 4, 3)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn_sign, 5, 0)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn0, 5, 1)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn_dot, 5, 2)
        main_gridlayout.addWidget(btn_equal, 5, 3)
        
        self.setLayout(main_gridlayout)
        self.show()

mw = MainWindow()

app.exec_()
```

**Before clicking the button**

[image: Before_button_clicked]

**After clicking the button**

[image: AFter_button_clicked]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Note: this answer is mostly intended for *didactic* purposes. It somehow goes way beyond (or far away from) the original request, and has conceptual issues both in its resolution and result. Nonetheless, I believe it could be really educational for many (even unrelated) aspects of Python and Qt that are often misunderstood or completely unknown.</sup>

### Premise (what's wrong with the OP code)

There are many issues with your approach, starting with the peculiar mix of OOP and "pseudo-procedural" paradigm.

The issue you're describing is caused by the fact that you're creating a *new* instance of the `MainWindow`, which in turn *reparents* all the previously declared widgets. Coincidentally, that main window instance has no reference at all, it's just a local variable, and python will *garbage collect* it as soon as the `button_click` function returns.

The result is that that window will be immediately destroyed after that, and all widgets that have been reparented to that window will be also destroyed along with it.

What you see is the only remaining widgets (the "display").

Not only: from the OOP perspective, a "child" object should never directly act upon its parent object(s) in its hierarchy. It's not the responsibility of the button to change something in its parent.

### Hierarchy of objects and their responsibilities

Let me take this from a pseudo-real-life perspective.

As many of us have probably realized, children just behave on their education, no matter of the context. They just do or tell what they've been "taught", *bluntly*.

Imagine that the "window" is the teacher in a school class, and the buttons are the pupils. The teacher has the responsibility of those students, the lesson is about "solving a math problem" that can be written on the chalkboard. It is the teacher's responsibility to decide what would be written to the chalkboard based on the actions of the children, not the other way around.

What you're trying to do is that whenever a new student is called to intervene, they will *create a new teacher* and a new chalkboard, then write whatever they choose, no matter what was written before.

That's clearly wrong: lots of cool doodles, but not very *educational*.

And that's not all:

- the previous teacher will be left with an empty class and their chalkboard with the original text: "0" (that is what you're seeing);
- the newly created teacher/class/chalkboard and also all their students will immediately "disappear" due to the garbage collection;

So. First of all, the button (as the pupil) should have no direct responsibility, it can only *signal* that they want to do something.

The window (the teacher) will *decide* what to do with the student's will, based on a set of rules (the pedagogy they learnt).

Most importantly, the pupils are *assigned* to the teacher's *class* (pun intended), they shouldn't be moved at will, and certainly *not* by direct will of one of those children.

Now, with the above in mind, let's make a "sign" for each pupil, so that they can write their own symbol on it and tell the teacher that they have been "called". The teacher sees their sign and will decide what to write on the chalkboard.
In Qt terms, that *sign* is a **signal**. We assign them a symbol, and when they're called they will "show" (*emit*) that symbol (*signal*):

```py
class Button(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    buttonClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super().__init__(text, parent=parent)
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, 
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)

        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Helvetica', 20))
        self.clicked.connect(lambda: self.buttonClicked.emit(text))
```

Now, let's make a good *class*. Children usually go wherever they like, the teacher should keep some "order" and tell them where to sit. We have the *names* of those children (or, better, their "symbols"), let's put them in a proper *layout*, so that the teacher always know the position of each child and their "symbol" and remember them where to sit every day. For instance:

```py
buttons = [
    ['%', 'CE', 'Back', '/'], 
    ['7', '8', '9', '×'], 
    ['4', '5', '6', '-'], 
    ['1', '2', '3', '+'], 
    ['+/-', '0', '.', '='], 
]
```

But the whole class layout is also important. The chalkboard is "on top", then the children desks. We use a "main layout" for the whole classroom, on top we put the chalkboard, then the "grid" of desks.

And, now that we're at it, we also define what those "sign[al]s" will do.

Let's see our *class*:

```py
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Calculator')
        
        # this is our chalkboard! yay!
        self.display = QtWidgets.QLabel("0")
        self.display.setStyleSheet("background-color: #e3e1da;\
                                border: 1px solid black;\
                                padding-top: 10px;\
                                padding-bottom: 10px")
        self.display.setMaximumHeight(100)
        self.display.setAlignment(
            QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)        
        self.display.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Helvetica', 40))
        
        # the *main* layout of the class
        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        # the chalkboard is on "top"
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.display)

        # all student's desks after that
        buttonLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout)

        # the desk layout
        buttons = [
            ['%', 'CE', 'Back', '/'], 
            ['7', '8', '9', '×'], 
            ['4', '5', '6', '-'], 
            ['1', '2', '3', '+'], 
            ['+/-', '0', '.', '='], 
        ]

        for row, rowButtons in enumerate(buttons):
            for column, text in enumerate(rowButtons):
                button = Button(text)
                button.buttonClicked.connect(self.updateDisplay)
                buttonLayout.addWidget(button, row, column)
```

We only miss our main *assignment*, common for each of those *sign[al]s*:

```py
    def updateDisplay(self, text):
        if self.display.text() == '0':
            self.display.clear()
        self.display.setText(self.display.text() + text)
```

Oh, wait, there's one child with the "Back" signal. We have to take care of that too! Just ensure that they don't clear the whole chalkboard or write something weird!

```py
    def updateDisplay(self, text):
        if text == 'Back' and self.display.text() != '0':
            self.display.setText(self.display.text()[:-1])
        elif self.display.text() == '0':
            self.display.clear()
        self.display.setText(self.display.text() + text)
```

Ok, now we're pretty set.

But.
No. That's not enough.

Unfortunately, calculators are quite complex: they display something that is logical *to us*, but might not make a lot of sense mathematically speaking.

But, that's for another time. Class is over!

Comment: Oh my god. I can't believe there would be such a big help out on here as you are. I can't appreciate you enough. Thank you so much for explaining my problems in great detail. I felt like I just came out of a classroom! Thank you!!!!

Comment: Just sent you a small donation to show my appreciation ;)

Comment: @Ryan You're very welcome (and, also, thank you). Note that I made some modifications (I expanded the explanation a bit and fixed some small issues).